# Pad an image with 10 Pixel with color of 0th pixel

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

**My use case** : 
I want to add a border of 10 pixel to the image using the ImageOps.expand method in the PIL. It asks for a fill value the default being black.
I researched and found that in order to find the color value of a pixel,
you need to do

`pix = im.load() 
 im = ImageOps.expand(im, border=10, fill=pix[0,0])`

**Issue**:
I am not able to pass this `pix[x,y]` value to the expand method. I went through the [method definition](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/ImageOps.py) and can't find the exact reason this is failing. [This](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.expand) is the official documentation of the PIL that asks you to send a fill value.

[I am able to get this kind of image. The only thing that is wrong is the annoying white border even though i am using the fill value as pix[0,0].](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1ql9.png)

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Mudits It is giving a white border.

Comment: Please provide your actual input image, rather than a picture of it beside the result image. Often issues are the result of the image itself.

Comment: can we use anyother library then this ?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

img = Image.open('skooter.png')

x, y = 0, 0
pix = img.load()
img2 = ImageOps.expand(img, border=10, fill=pix[x,y])
img2.show()
```

Result:

[image: resulting image (img2)]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. The color value for the border is different from the background. The border needs to be a continuation of the background.

Comment: `pix[0, 0]` _is_ `(0, 0, 0)` in my test image, so the result shown is correct. If I hardcode `ImageOps.expand(img, border=10, fill=(255, 0, 0))` the result has a red border, as expected. Hard to tell what's going on without your actual code along with the actual image being used.